# Getting error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" when I use lambda in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Testing pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) API:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

z = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(5, 5))
z.sort()

df = pd.DataFrame(z)

def mkp(s):
    return s.pow(s)

mkpow = lambda s: 10 if s < 50 else s.pow(s)

df.apply(mkp) // works fine
df.apply(mkpow) // this line gives error
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What's the cause and how to resolve it?

Comment: The cause and some possible resolutions are both _in the message_. The fact that you're doing it in a lambda is irrelevant, as would be clearer if your two functions actually did the same thing.

Comment: The problem is in this part: `if s < 50.` The result of `s < 50` is not True or False, but a boolean Series, which is an array of True and False values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are comparing a list with a number and it causes an error. You could change your lambda function with something like this:

```
mkpow = lambda i: [10 if s < 50 else s.pow(s) for s in i]
enter code here
```

or you could Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() as suggested in the exception text:

```
mkpow = lambda s: 10 if (s < 50).all() else s.pow(s)
```

I do not understand your purpose so I don't know which one suits your needs, but both are syntaxical true.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand where was the problem.